# MacBook Pro 15 uses 60+ GB of swap memory

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, crash, virtual-memory

So, today something quite weird happened. I was watching a video on my MacBook Pro, and I noticed the fans started to ramp up quite a bit. I didn't think too much of it at first, since it often struggles to drive to drive the 2 external monitors that I have hooked up to it (one's 1080p, the other is 4K), but this time it started getting really loud, so I closed some applications that I wasn't using to see if that would fix it. It did for a moment, but after a few minutes, I got a prompt message saying I ran out of memory:

[image: Your system has run out of application memory prompt.]

I closed everything except for Firefox and even relaunched Finder, but the prompt message wouldn't go away, no matter how many applications and processes I killed. One of the applications that I manually quit was NTFS for Mac, and before I closed it, I caught a glimpse of my storage summary and noticed that I had about 7 GB left, which I knew for a fact wasn't true because I just factory reset this computer about a week ago. I re-opened Activity Monitor to force quit some more processes, only to find out that not only was I out of RAM, but the reason why I was running out of storage space was because the laptop was using so much swap memory!

[image: Activity Monitor's Memory tab.]

I realize Firefox's web content processes were using quite a bit of memory, but even that shouldn't have been enough to bring my MacBook Pro 15 Late 2018 to its knees (it was using about ~3GB of memory if my math is correct). After a while trying to free up as much memory as I could, my MacBook just couldn't handle it anymore and crashed on me. I left it untouched for a few minutes to let it cool down, and when I turned it back on, it struggled to boot and took a very long while to sign into my account.

I couldn't find anything similar to this problem with a quick Google search, so I was wondering if something like this has happened to anyone else.

Comment: The system is doing amazingly well for the amount of memory being leaked. What’s your tolerance to reboot and not use Firefox for several hours to make sure it’s not just that? I’ve seen this all the time with chrome and Firefox and extensions so your basic question is yes, this happens to people.

Comment: @bmike I could give up Firefox for a while if that's what your asking. However, after the crash happened and it rebooted, I opened Firefox (nothing more, just Firefox and Activity Monitor) and nothing's happened for the last hour or so that it's been running. Do you happen to have an idea as to what is happening or how I could fix it? It really doesn't seem like Firefox is the problem, or at least I can't think of a particular reason why Firefox would leak so much memory.

Comment: I’m not super good at picking apart those browsers. How long after boot was the memory pressure graph? (You probably want all processes as well going forward as you track things). Getting sysdiagnose immediately after boot and then once you detect leaking is the best way to prove what’s culpable. Something is leaking a lot of memory, so it’s going to be easy to triage I think.

Comment: @bmike that memory pressure graph screenshot in the question was taken during the computer's memory leakage and crashing process (I'm not even sure how I was able to take the screenshot to be honest, everything was pretty laggy). Right now, memory pressure is all green and normal, and 0 bytes of swap is being used. I could add a current screenshot as an edit to the original question if that helps.

Comment: What happened is clear, now you wait for it to come back...

Comment: I guess I'll have to try to recreate it then (although it wasn't a pretty experience, I guess it's better than leaving the issue unattended). I'm thinking maybe something in VSCode could've gone crazy, so I'll try to follow your suggestion, see if I can find the culprit. Thanks, I'll update this question if I find the culprit or a solution to this issue.

Comment: I'm with bmike - definitely switch Activity Monitor to All Processes, in the View menu. btw, the Swap Used is a 'high tide' marker, so even though your machine was seemingly recovering from the peak usage at the time that screenshot was taken, the Swap figure would likely not go down until reboot. [I've never seen it so high, so it *may* do some reallocation after so much stress, I'm not absolutely sure]